# fastify should I decorate the pg in this case or is it useless?

Tags: fastify

I am new on fastify and I want to use pg. I have two options for a querie.

(db.ts)

```
import { Pool } from 'pg';
 
const pool = new Pool({
  host: 'xxx',
  user: 'postgres',
  port: xxx,
  database: 'postgres',
  password: 'xxx',
  max: 20,
  idleTimeoutMillis: 30000,
  connectionTimeoutMillis: 2000,
});

export default pool;
```

First option:

```
import Fastify from 'fastify';
import { pool } from 'db/db.ts';

const fastify = Fastify();

async function main() {

  fastify.get('/', async (req, reply) => {
    return await pool.query('SELECT * FROM users');
  });

  try {
    await fastify.listen({
      port: 3000,
      host: '0.0.0.0'
    });
    console.log('SERVER LISTEN');
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    process.exit(1);
  }
}

main();
```

Second option with decorate

```
import Fastify from 'fastify';
import { pool } from 'db/db.ts';
import { Pool } from 'pg';

const fastify = Fastify();

declare module "Fastify" {
  export interface FastifyInstance {
    pg_: Pool
  }
}

fastify.decorate('pg_', pool);

async function main() {

  fastify.get('/', async (req, reply) => {
    return await fastify.pg_.query('SELECT * FROM users');
  });

  try {
    await fastify.listen({
      port: 3000,
      host: '0.0.0.0'
    });
    console.log('SERVER LISTEN');
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    process.exit(1);
  }
}

main();
```

so is the second option useless ?

I also learn microservice and I want to ask you which way you prefer when also building it with microservice

thank you very much

..................................................

Comment: Consider to use https://github.com/fastify/fastify-postgres . adding a decorator is correct - will need some hours to write down a complete answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use the plugin [fastify-postgres](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-postgres) it works with typescript and support all the features of postgress on your app.

On repo you will have all examples